# Python - PyQt - QTable Widget - adding rows

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

i am new to PyQt and still bit confused anyhow. I have a text file structure like this:

- Name   Surname    Telephone    Email

Where spaces are actually tabs " \t " now when i read this file whit my method i wish to populate the QTable Widget.

My QTable Widget has 4 columns called `Name`, `Surname`, `Telephone`, `Email` now it has no rows but as I read lines from the file and split each line by tabulator I wish to add a new row that in each column contains whatever was in the line.

Could someone point me in the direction how to go about this because I cannot find a solution or a method offered by QTable Widget that allows you to this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you want to populate `QTableWidget`, you need to set row and column counts before inserting data [example in documentation](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html) (PySide documentation is better than PyQt). And you can't just insert text string separated by tabs into table, you need to prepare it yourself, and then populate table with `QTableWidgetItem`'s by calling `QTableWidget.setItem`. It will look like this:

```
entries = []
with open('data') as input:
    for line in input:
        entries.append(line.strip().split('\t'))

tableWidget.setRowCount(len(entries))
tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(entries[0]))

for i, row in enumerate(entries):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        item = QTableWidgetItem(col)
        tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)
```

I'm assuming that you have `data` file with your entries, and `tableWidget` is `QTableWidget` instance.

In this example file parsed by hand, but consider using standart [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) for this task.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed my gui app where my method reads file by lines and appends lines to a list as you did. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For some python beginner, like me: I believe to use QTableWidgetItem you have to import QtGui from PyQt4 (from PyQt4 import QtCore, QyGui) and use QtGui.QTableWidgetItem instead of QTableWidgetItem alone.