# Python QT - Search the txt file and show the results in TableWidget

Tags: python, qt

Its simple as it can be, but I cant do it.

I have txt file which contains name,surname, mail and telephone number like that:

```
name surname phone mail 
name surname phone mail
name surname phone mail
```

Everything is seperated with tabs and after the mail there is newline at the end of each line

Now I want to search the file for the specific name im searching and to show the results when I click the button Search in TableWidget (using python Qt).

Its simple, but I have some errors I cant resolve.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Are you having problems getting the data into your tables model? Or are you having problems with the table widget itself?

Comment: First part is very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8775447/1052325). Is it homework?. Provide code and errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possible steps to accomplish here.

1. Read the data into your model
2. Interact with your tablewidget and your search field

To get your started, a simple and straightforward approach for reading in your data would be to use the csv module. You could also create a custom table model that would read directly from a csv file, but I think thats beyond our level right now.

Here is a simple way to get your text file into a data structure:

```
import csv

people = []
reader = csv.reader(open('people.txt'), delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    people.append(row)
```

Now people will contain all your lines in the form: (name, surname, email)

From here, you can populate your TableWidget. This is a really basic snippet that should give you the idea:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

rowCount = len(people)
colCount = max([len(p) for p in people])

tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget()
tableWidget.setRowCount(rowCount)
tableWidget.setColumnCount(colCount)

for row, person in enumerate(people):
    for column, value in enumerate(person):
        newItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(value)
        tableWidget.setItem(row, column, newItem)
```

The colCount is just a little protection in case you have unbalanced amounts of fields on each line. Again this is just a general approach.

From here its a little open ended as to how you want to do the search. But what you could do is connect you search button to a method that handles the search. Keep in mind I am writing all this as just global functions. You would probably have your class, and be using `self` everywhere. But I am keeping it short and simple:

```
myButton.clicked.connect(search)

def search(*args, **kwargs):
    value = myLineEdit.text()
    items = tableWidget.findItems(value, QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
    if items:
        # scroll to the first match?
        tableWidget.scrollToItem(items[0], tableWidget.PositionAtCenter)
```