# Python - PyQt - QTable Widget - Add Value, Not Key

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt4, qtablewidget

[This post contained nearly the solution I was looking for, but not quite.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775447/python-pyqt-qtable-widget-adding-rows)

I have data that I retrieve from MySQL, which resides in what I think is a tuple, though it also looks like a dictionary:

```
{'client_contact': 'John Doe', 'client_state': 'CA', ...}
```

I have this code, but when I run it, it generates the key instead of the value:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM client_info")
rows = cur.fetchall()

for i, row in enumerate(rows):
  for j, col in enumerate(row):
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(col)
    self.ui.tblVIEW.setItem(i, j, item)
```

The "col" variable above keeps returning 'client_contact' in rows[0] and 'client_state' in rows[1] instead of 'John Doe' and 'CA'.

Should I be iterating through the tuples/dictionary differently? Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any feedback you may have to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a dict. try to iterate with `for j, col in enumerate(row.values())`

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed to do. I made this change and it worked as desired.