# Comparing QLineEdit() and csv file values

Tags: python, csv, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm using PyQt5 and want to compare values from a csv file with values imputed by the user through QLineEdit(). Then, if the values are the same, I want to get the whole row imported to a QTableWidget.

The csv file contains 3 different columns, with width values, height values and thickness values.

I've tried this to solve the first problem:

```
import csv
with open('csvTest.csv') as file:

    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == self.widthTextbox.text() or row[1] == self.heightTextbox.text() or row[2] == self.thickTextbox.text():
            print("Found: {}".format(row))
```

This didn't work, and I know that using "or" is problematic because I want this to act like a filter, so if the user only inputs one of the three atributes he'll get some rows, if he inputs two he'll get fewer rows and if he inputs all three of them he will get even fewer. But using "or" allows any line that fits any condition valid.

The second problem is, if this worked, I'd like to make the number of rows in the table equal to the number of rows that passed through the filter, using something like `self.tableWidget.setRowCount('''number of rows found''')` .

Finally, the last issue would be to make the QTableWidget rows identical to the ones that the filter found.

Answer (score 0):

To solve first and second issue this could be a way:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter


rows_finded = []
with open('csvTest.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        values = [self.widthTextbox.text(), self.heightTextbox.text(), self.thickTextbox.text()]
        if Counter(values) == Counter(row):
            rows_finded.append(row)

self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(rows_finded))
```

To solve last issue (source: [Python - PyQt - QTable Widget - adding rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775447/python-pyqt-qtable-widget-adding-rows)):

```
for i, row in enumerate(rows_finded):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        item = QTableWidgetItem(col)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)
```

Comment: I think the code for solving the last issue is pretty smart and works, but I still haven't managed to make the first part work. In a separated file I've setted the values like `values = [65, 175, 30]` and tried to print the list with the appended values, but even with the values I've setted in the csv file, the list was always empty.